# Do Rust traits have runtime overhead?

Tags: rust, traits, dynamic-dispatch, static-dispatch

Is there any runtime overhead if I create `c1` of type `Concrete1` in the code below?

```
pub trait ExampleTrait {
    fn foo(&self);
}

pub struct Concrete1 {}

impl ExampleTrait for Concrete1 {
    fn foo(&self) {}
}

pub struct Concrete2 {}

impl ExampleTrait for Concrete2 {
    fn foo(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let c1 = Concrete1 {};
    c1.foo();
}
```

Does this entail any sort of v-table lookup or any other kind of overhead? I want a trait so that I can enforce at compile time that both `Concrete1` and `Concrete2` implement the same set of methods.

I will statically choose which concrete type to use in the main program; the two implementations exist just so that I can use an alternative implementation of the trait if need arises.

Comment: No. Dynamic dispatch is only [performed by trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html?highlight=dispatch#trait-objects-perform-dynamic-dispatch).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the concrete type is known statically, then static dispatch is used.

If the concrete type is not known (i.e. a trait object: `&dyn ExampleTrait`), then dynamic dispatch is used.

See also:

- [What are the actual runtime performance costs of dynamic dispatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28621980/155423)